# Ive only started coding in python for about a month. Can I overwrite previously parsed data? Question continued in the body

Tags: python, finance, yahoo-finance

I wrote a function that would gather information on a particular stock after parsing it from yahoo finance. Now at the end of the function, I would leave the user the option to search another quote or go back to the homepage. When the user clicks this option, the program crashes, saying the arrays must all be the same length. I assume since the data that was gathered from the previous quote was already registered within the function, and wont allow the user to overwrite and parse. How would i fix this problem? Please advise.

```
import random
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

def tickersymbol():
    tickersymbol = input("What company would you like information on?") 
    url = ('https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+tickersymbol+'?p='+tickersymbol+'&.tsrc=fin-srch')
    response = requests.get(url) 
    htmltext = response.text

    for indicator in Indicators :

        splitlist = htmltext.split(indicator)
        afterfirstsplit =splitlist[1].split("\">")[2]
        aftersecondsplit = afterfirstsplit.split("</span>")
        datavalue = aftersecondsplit[0]
        Indicators[indicator].append(datavalue)

    for values in Misc:
        splitlist = htmltext.split(values)
        afterfirstsplit =splitlist[1].split("\">")[1]
        aftersecondsplit = afterfirstsplit.split("</td>")
        netset = aftersecondsplit[0]
        Misc[values].append(netset)

    Indicators.update(Misc)
    df = pd.DataFrame(Indicators)
    array = np.transpose(df)
    print(array)

    task = input('''
                 Would you like to continue? 

                 [1] : Yes, Look at another Symbol     ##Here is where the problem starts. 
                 [2] : No, Go back to main 

                   ''')

    if task == "1":
        return tickersymbol()
    elif task == "2":
        return main()
    else:
        print("Try to answer that one again")
```

Indicators =

{"Previous Close" : [], "Open" : [], "Bid" : [] , "Ask": [], 'Volume': [], 'Avg. Volume': [], 'Market Cap': [], 'Beta': [], 'PE Ratio (TTM)': [], 'EPS (TTM)': [], 'Earnings Date': [], 'Ex-Dividend Date': [], '1y Target Est' : []}

Misc =

{'52 Week Range' :[], "Day's Range": [], 'Dividend & Yield' : []}

Comment: Your code does not run.  An issue with `for indicator in Indicators :`.  Variable Indicators is not defined.  Also missing main().

Comment: @vanguardcoder--stackoverflow encourages adding all updates to the post rather than comments so relevant information can be easily found.

Comment: Thank you., Please see my revised post with the updated variables.

Comment: @vanguardcoder--posted an answer. Could you check if it runs for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue found with software was line:

```
tickersymbol = input("What company would you like information on?")
```

Since this is the same as the function name, this causes an error when you try to call the function again i.e.

```
return tickersymbol()
```

Remedy, change line to:

```
tickersymbol_ = input("What company would you like information on?") 
url = ('https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+tickersymbol_+'?p='+tickersymbol_+'&.tsrc=fin-srch')
```

**Other Revisions**

1. error checking -- use try/except block
2. control flow--use while loop rather than function calling itself
3. indicator and misc--inside function so they are reset for each stock processed
4. main calls tickersymbol, which returns to it upon completion

**Revised Code**

```
import random
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

def main():
  tickersymbol()

def tickersymbol():
    while True:
      skip = False

      tickersymbol_ = input("What company would you like information on?") 
      url = ('https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+tickersymbol_+'?p='+tickersymbol_+'&.tsrc=fin-srch')
      response = requests.get(url) 
      htmltext = response.text

      # Reset Indicator and Misc
      Indicators = {"Previous Close" : [], "Open" : [], "Bid" : [] , "Ask": [], 'Volume': [], 'Avg. Volume': [], 'Market Cap': [], 'Beta': [], 'PE Ratio (TTM)': [], 'EPS (TTM)': [], 'Earnings Date': [], 'Ex-Dividend Date': [], '1y Target Est' : []} 

      Misc = {'52 Week Range' :[], "Day&#x27;s Range": [], 'Dividend &amp; Yield' : []} 

      for indicator in Indicators :
          try:
            splitlist = htmltext.split(indicator)
            afterfirstsplit =splitlist[1].split("\">")[2]
            aftersecondsplit = afterfirstsplit.split("</span>")
            datavalue = aftersecondsplit[0]
            Indicators[indicator].append(datavalue)
          except:
            print('Error with stock')
            skip = True
            break

      if skip:
        continue     # continues with the outer while loop

      for values in Misc:
          try:
            splitlist = htmltext.split(values)
            afterfirstsplit =splitlist[1].split("\">")[1]
            aftersecondsplit = afterfirstsplit.split("</td>")
            netset = aftersecondsplit[0]
            Misc[values].append(netset)
          except:
            print('Error with stock')
            skip = True
            break

      if skip:
        continue    # continues with outer while loop

      Indicators.update(Misc)
      df = pd.DataFrame(Indicators)
      array = np.transpose(df)
      print(array)

      task = input('''
                  Would you like to continue? 

                  [1] : Yes, Look at another Symbol     ##Here is where the problem starts. 
                  [2] : No, Go back to main 

                    ''')

      if task == "1":
          continue    # continues with outer while loop
      elif task == "2":
          return      # done with tickersymbol function
      else:
          print("Try to answer that one again")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I know you said you've only been programming for like a month, but please work on variable naming. I don't blame you for not knowing the case conventions for Python, but you noticed how `ticker_symbol` is a good name for the inputted ticket symbol, but that should've also told you that `tickersymbol` as a function name is bad; it doesn't tell me what the function does! Perhaps call the function `get_stock_data`?

Comment: @GregSchmit--I didn't modify OP variable names since thought too many changes may make it harder to follow the changes needed to make the code at least work.   Further cleanup is helpful and could benefit from the [PEP 8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: That fixed it! Adding the indicators and misc variables into the function also fixed the issue too. But you improved it as well by adding a while statement in case the user inputs an invalid quote. I did not expect i would be using a try and except for this function. I appreciate the guide for naming conventions and the assistance on the config. Thank you @DarrylG!

Comment: Lol, sorry @DarryIG I read your answer as the OP's self-answer for some reason. Yeah, that comment was directed at the OP.